# Mapping Entities with inherited classes

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have RCM and RCS class, both inherit from RC, I want that entity generate only RCM and RCS tables. I have the following method on my context class:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Cliente>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("Cliente");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("Usuario");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<RCS>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("RCS");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<RCM>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("RCM");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<MaterialPedido>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("MaterialPedido");
        });
    }
```

Other classes that have inherit works fine, but the RC table have been generated too.

RC, RCM and RCS classes.

```
public abstract class RC
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Numero { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Obra é obrigatório!")]
    public virtual Obra Obra { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Usuario Ususario { get; set; }
}

public class RCM : RC
{
    public DateTime DataNecessidade { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Os Materiais são obrigatórios!")]
    public List<MaterialRCM> Materiais { get; set; }

    public RCM()
    {

    }

    public RCM(int ID, String Numero, Obra Obra, DateTime Data, DateTime DataNecessidade, List<MaterialRCM> Materiais, int Cod_Usuario)
    {
        base.ID = ID;
        base.Numero = Numero;
        base.Obra = Obra;
        base.Data = Data;
        this.DataNecessidade = DataNecessidade;
        this.Materiais = Materiais;
        base.Ususario.ID = Cod_Usuario;
    }
}
```

}

```
public class RCS : RC
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Serviço é obrigatório!")]
    public String Servico { get; set; }

    public DateTime DtaInicial { get; set; }

    public DateTime DtaFinal { get; set; }

    public RCS()
    {

    }

    public RCS(int ID, String Numero, Obra Obra, String Servico, DateTime Data, DateTime DtaInicial, DateTime DtaFinal, int Cod_Usuario)
    {
        base.ID = ID;
        base.Numero = Numero;
        base.Obra = Obra;
        this.Servico = Servico;
        base.Data = Data;
        this.DtaInicial = DtaInicial;
        this.DtaFinal = DtaFinal;
        base.Ususario.ID = Cod_Usuario;
    }

}
```

Comment: What's in the RC table? Show classes for `RC`, `RCS` and `RCM`.

Comment: @user3670112, Is there any class that has property of type `RC` `public RC RC { get; set; }` ?

Comment: I post the classes code. there is no property type RC.

Comment: I was investigating all calsses on project and I found a class that has a property type RC, I remove it and the RC table is not generated anymore. thanks to all.